# Update one drop-down list from another

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I am using boostrap library to create two drop down list. I would like the items in the second dropdown to update based on the item selected in the first dropdown

I have a dictionary *data* whose keys are the items of the first dropdown list and the values ​​will populate the second dropdown list depending on the chosen key

*fill_category* function creates an html structure ul whose elements of li will be filled with the values ​​of the key

What I do is I get the ul structure (the second dropdown) then I replace it with the result of fill_category

When I first select a key in the first drop-down list, the second drop-down list is updated and I can select an item from the second drop-down list.
But when I select a key a second time the second drop-down list no longer unfolds. Yet the second drop-down list is updated well in the html code

```js
let data = {"A" : ["A1" , "A2"],
                "B" : ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                "C" : ['C1']
};

function fill_categorie(tableau) {
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  ul.classList.add("dropdown-menu");
 
  for (let i = 0; i < tableau.length; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("dropdown-item");
    li.textContent = `${tableau[i]}`;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    
  }
  return ul
  
}

function select_btn(button) {

  const ulElement = button.nextElementSibling;
  const dropdownItems = ulElement.querySelectorAll("li");
  
  function waitForClick() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      dropdownItems.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const selectedText = item.textContent.trim();
          resolve(selectedText);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  async function getValue() {
    const selectedText = await waitForClick();
    return selectedText
  }


  getValue().then(value => { 
    button.textContent = value
    if(button.id == "btnID") updateListLabel(value)
  }); 



}

function updateListLabel(selectedElem) {

  const ctg = data[selectedElem]; 
  console.log(ctg)
  const btn_ctg = document.getElementById("btn2ID")
  const oldUl_ctg = btn_ctg.nextElementSibling;  
  const newUl_ctg = fill_categorie(ctg);          
  const parent_ctg = btn_ctg.parentNode;            
  parent_ctg.replaceChild(newUl_ctg, oldUl_ctg);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
   <div>
      <h5>DropDown 1</h5>
      <div class="dropdown">
         <button id="btnID" onclick="select_btn(this)" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
            type="button"data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
         DropDown1
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="">
            <li class="dropdown-item ">A</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item ">B</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item ">C</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <br><br>
   </div>
   <h5>DropDown 2</h5>
   <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="btn2ID" onclick="select_btn(this)" class="btn btn-secondary
         dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      DropDown 2
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu"> </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to stylize the select component, Bootstrap uses your li in order to create its custom component.

But since you've changed the li directly, Bootstrap doesn't rebuild the Dropdown component.

One way you could ask Bootstrap to rebuild it's component is using the update method, like so:

```
new bootstrap.Dropdown(document.querySelector('#btn2Id')).update()
```

As descripbed in the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/#methods

Therefore your "updateListLabel" could be changed into:

```
 function updateListLabel(selectedElem) {

  const ctg = data[selectedElem]; 
  console.log(ctg)
  const btn_ctg = document.getElementById("btn2ID")
  const oldUl_ctg = btn_ctg.nextElementSibling;  
  const newUl_ctg = fill_categorie(ctg);          
  const parent_ctg = btn_ctg.parentNode;            
  parent_ctg.replaceChild(newUl_ctg, oldUl_ctg);

  new bootstrap.Dropdown(document.querySelector('#btn2Id')).update()
}
```

Working example:

```js
let data = {"A" : ["A1" , "A2"],
                "B" : ['B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                "C" : ['C1']
};

function fill_categorie(tableau) {
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  ul.classList.add("dropdown-menu");
 
  for (let i = 0; i < tableau.length; i++) {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.classList.add("dropdown-item");
    li.textContent = `${tableau[i]}`;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    
  }
  return ul
  
}

function select_btn(button) {

  const ulElement = button.nextElementSibling;
  const dropdownItems = ulElement.querySelectorAll("li");
  
  function waitForClick() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      dropdownItems.forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('click', () => {
          const selectedText = item.textContent.trim();
          resolve(selectedText);
        });
      });
    });
  }

  async function getValue() {
    const selectedText = await waitForClick();
    return selectedText
  }


  getValue().then(value => { 
    button.textContent = value
    if(button.id == "btnID") updateListLabel(value)
  }); 



}

function updateListLabel(selectedElem) {

  const ctg = data[selectedElem]; 
  console.log(ctg)
  const btn_ctg = document.getElementById("btn2ID")
  const oldUl_ctg = btn_ctg.nextElementSibling;  
  const newUl_ctg = fill_categorie(ctg);          
  const parent_ctg = btn_ctg.parentNode;            
  parent_ctg.replaceChild(newUl_ctg, oldUl_ctg);


  new bootstrap.Dropdown(document.querySelector('#btn2ID')).update()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
   <div>
      <h5>DropDown 1</h5>
      <div class="dropdown">
         <button id="btnID" onclick="select_btn(this)" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" 
            type="button"data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
         DropDown1
         </button>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="">
            <li class="dropdown-item ">A</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item ">B</li>
            <li class="dropdown-item ">C</li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <br><br>
   </div>
   <h5>DropDown 2</h5>
   <div class="dropdown">
      <button id="btn2ID" onclick="select_btn(this)" class="btn btn-secondary
         dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      DropDown 2
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu"> </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A bit like the other question I misread minutes back. A drop-down list is done with a "select" whereas a "menu" may well contain ul tag.